# File saving in excel

Tags: excel, vba

There is a code written under a button click to save the workbook content to a txt file

**Code**:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlBook As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Dim strOutputFileName

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\bera02a\Desktop\Arun_TAT_Testing_orig_14022013.xls")

    For Each xlSheet In xlBook.Worksheets
        strOutputFileName = "C:\Documents and Settings\bera02a\Desktop\" & xlSheet.Name & ".txt"
        xlSheet.SaveAs Filename:=strOutputFileName, FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText
    Next
    xlApp.Quit
End Sub
```

**Original line  in workbook**:

`create table abc as select rpt2_id, rpt2_usgcount, rpt2_usgdate, rpt2_usgmins from rpt2 where rpt2_id = 'xyz;`

**Output is coming as**:

`"create table abc as select rpt2_id, rpt2_usgcount, rpt2_usgdate, rpt2_usgmins from rpt2 where rpt2_id = 'xyz;"`

Thee output is coming with double quotes at the start and end and it is only coming for the insert and create statements present in the workbook.

Can anyone help me in not getting that quotes in the output.?

Comment: peter has helpmed me last time in gettnig the solution related to excel.if he could help me in this too

Comment: Please follow @SiddharthRout suggestion and take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb241279%28v=office.12%29.aspx Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you have asked for Peter's help specifically but see if this is what you want?

```
xlSheet.SaveAs Filename:=strOutputFileName, FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter
```

**FOLLOWUP (From Comments)**

Try this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim xlBook As Workbook, xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim strOutputFileName As String
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String, MyArray() As String
    Dim strPath As String

    strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path '<~~ \\plyalnppd3sm\d$\Temp\Arun\TAT\

    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs strPath & "\Temp.xls"

    Set xlBook = Workbooks.Open(strPath & "\Temp.xls")

    For Each xlSheet In xlBook.Worksheets
        If xlSheet.Name <> "User_provided_data" Then
            strOutputFileName = strPath & "\" & xlSheet.Name & ".zup"
            xlSheet.SaveAs Filename:=strOutputFileName, FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS

            n = n + 1

            ReDim Preserve MyArray(n)
            MyArray(n) = strOutputFileName
            Debug.Print strOutputFileName
        End If
    Next

    xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Kill strPath & "\Temp.xls"

    For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)
        '~~> open the files in One go and store them in an array
        Open MyArray(i) For Binary As #1
        MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
        Get #1, , MyData
        Close #1
        strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

        '~~> Write to the text file
        Open MyArray(i) For Output As #1

        '~~> Loop through the array and check if the start and end has "
        '~~> And if it does then ignore those and write to the text file
        For j = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
            If Left(strData(j), 1) = """" And Right(strData(j), 1) = """" Then
                strData(j) = Mid(strData(j), 2, Len(strData(j)) - 2)
            End If
            Print #1, strData(j)
        Next j
        Close #1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @user2075017 be aware about limitations: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/533885-fileformat-xltextprinter-saves-only-240-characters-of-cell.html

Comment: @user2075017: That is because it is beyond 256 characters. See the limitation in the link given above. I can give you an alternative code which can remove the `"` from the beginning and the end if you prefer?

Comment: @user2075017 if you follow the link you'll find a proposed solution to bypass that limitation. Moreover, that's another question.

Comment: Send me the file when u reach home and then we will take it from there? I believe the errors are happening because of some other error in the module `modAddin`

Comment: Hi Siddharth..I will send you the excel as soon as i reach home..meanwhile if you can sort me with the above mentioned error which i am getting in the output where "" is present the output is generated as """"

Comment: Hi Siddharth,I had uploaded the original file in the below mentioned shared path

http://www.wikiupload.com/MC05D9DUNDBG2N0

Comment: Ok wait I have another solution

Comment: Ok I am sure you do not want to create a text file for the 1st sheet `User_provided_data`

Comment: @SiddharthRout The issue still exists :( workbook contains the below info: CRITICAL; insert into ifparam values(3498,'TAT_UNALLOCTRADESREC','STRING','IF(STRING(C5)=STRING("TCE - External Hedge"),STRING("E"),IF(STRING(C5)=STRING("TCE - Internal Hedge""),STRING(""I""),STRING(C5)))');

But output comes as 

CRITICAL;
insert into ifparam values(3498,'TAT_UNALLOCTRADESREC','STRING','IF(STRING(C5)=STRING(""TCE - External Hedge""),STRING(""E""),IF(STRING(C5)=STRING(""TCE - Internal Hedge""),STRING(""I""),STRING(C5)))');

Issue is where ever there is " we are getting "" in output

Comment: @SiddharthRout hi..Any lucj on this please.i am still struggling for this.i couldnt get rid of the above mentioned errror.